# Is it possible to use deferenced pointers in initalization list

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to get my head around pointers/destruction and such. I'm using the code below to use pointer for x instead of a standard int; however if I use an initialization list in the constructor it won't compile, while if I just assign it normally in the constructor method it's works fine.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Point
{
private:
    int *x;
    int y;
public:
    Point(int x1, int y1):*x(x1),y(y1) {}

    // Copy constructor
    Point(const Point &p2) {*x = *p2.x; y = p2.y; }
   // ~Point(){delete x;}

    int getX()            {  return *x; }
    int getY()            {  return y; }
    void setX(int x1){*x=x1;}
};

int main()
{
    Point p1(10, 15); // Normal constructor is called here
    Point p2 = p1; // Copy constructor is called here
    p2.setX(35);

    // Let us access values assigned by constructors
    cout << "p1.x = " << p1.getX() << ", p1.y = " << p1.getY();
    cout << "\np2.x = " << p2.getX() << ", p2.y = " << p2.getY();

    return 0;
}
```

I also have a second question, which is the correct way to initize a int pointer like this:

```
int *p = new int;
*p = 3;
```

or like this:

```
int *p;
*p = 3;
```

I noticed if I assign nullptr or 0 and try to display the pointer it doesn't output anything is there a reason for this? eg:

```
int *p = 0;
*p = 3;
cout << *p;
```

Comment: You never make the pointer `Point::x` point anywhere, so each time you attempt to dereference it you will have *undefined behavior*. Also, `0` is the *null pointer* and is not a valid address, attempting to dereference a null pointer also leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Point(int x1, int y1):*x(x1),y(y1) {}` is not allowed syntax. You can only initialize **members** in the initialization lists, and `*x` is not a member. Btw, even if the compiler would allow it, it would produce undefined behaviour - you would be dereferencing an un-initialized pointer.

One way (at least, syntaxically correct and not leading to undefined behaviour in this very line) would be

```
 Point(int x1, int y1): x(new int(x1)), y(y1) {}
```

The second question actually is the same as the first. In the second example, you would be accessing the pointer without initializing it first, which would end up in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

When the constructor is called `Point(int x1, int y1):*x(x1)` , your x adress is not correct (not assigned), because it was not initialized so it can point anywhere in your RAM.

When you do `*x(x1)`, if it is allowed, you will:

- either corrupt your current memory
- either segfault